# C# use IDisposable or SafeHandle?

Tags: c#, idisposable

I have read a lot about finalizer and `IDisposable` in C#. As I finally become clear from this monstrous confusion over finalizer and `IDisposable`, suddenly, out of nowhere, there is this SafeHandle thing.
My belief is completely shaken again. What am I supposed to use?

Comment: Use for *what*, exactly?

Comment: Use for what, exactly. I don't know which one should I use in what situation now that there are 2 such seemingly similar constructs.

Comment: @HansPassant When reading the MSDN post about how to implement IDisposable, Microsoft presents two options how to implement that. One is implementing a finalizer, and the recommended one is using a SafeHandle. It's indeed a bit confusing and misleading, so I can understand OP's question very well. URL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/fs2xkftw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The website makes it sound very generic, so my first try to get my Pen objects properly disposed was also with SafeHandle, which was not very productive.

Comment: I think it is better stick with SafeHandle when you actually need to deal with handles that represents a kernel object (windows OS). If you want to wrap some unmanaged code, implement IDisposable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[SafeHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.aspx) is only useful when dealing with Win32 Interop calls. In Win32, most things are represented by "handles". This includes Windows, Mutexes, etc. So the .NET SafeHandle uses the disposable pattern to ensure the Win32 handle is properly closed.

So if you are using Win32 Interop calls and getting back Win32 handles, then use SafeHandle. For your own objects, you would stick with IDisposable and a finalizer.

Comment: But the whole point of [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx), is to release *unmanaged* resources, is not it? "your own objects" sounds ambiguous, as object can represent both a managed *and* unmanaged object, and since, you the developer, can develop both manged and unmanaged code and call your unmanaged code from your managed code your definition of "own" is also blurry.

Comment: @zespri - If you are deciding to implement IDisposable, that implies that you are maintaining the class/object (i.e. it's yours). If it's an object from a third-party library, then you can't implement IDisposable (i.e. it's not yours). I'm not referring to what should be disposed, nor will you be implementing IDisposable in unmanaged code.

Comment: But if it's an object from third-party (managed) library you can't implement `SafeHandle` either? Just because you are likely not to have any direct visibility of the handle in the first place anyway? Sorry, not being combative, just trying to understand what you mean.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "you can't implement `SafeHandle` either". You (in general) shouldn't be *deriving* from `SafeHandle`, only *using* when you are working with Interop calls. The original question asks whether he should be *derving* from `SafeHandle` or *implementing* `IDisposable`. The former is almost never a good idea. So that leaves us with the latter. And you can only implement `IDisposable` on classes/objects that you maintain (i.e. **your** classes/objects). So I'm guessing your confusion is that I used the work "objects" instead of "classes"?

Comment: It's getting too complicated, if you'd like we can just leave it there. I'm not quite sure why deriving from SafeHandle is almost never a good idea. In fact, I think in many cases (specifically when you are trying to wrap an unmanaged handle) it's a superior choice, because if you inherit from SafeHandle you can rest assured that Finalizer is implemented correctly for you. Now, while this is just tangential to my original query, it only confuses me more.

Answer (score 7):

You can/should use SafeHandle for any unamanaged resource which can be represented as IntPtr, i.e. Win32 handles, memory allocated by unmanaged code and so on. When SafeHandle isn't suitable, but you still need to handle unmanaged reources, consider making your own SafeHandle-like class inheriting from [CriticalFinalizerObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.constrainedexecution.criticalfinalizerobject.aspx).

In all other cases (i.e. handling managed resources) implement IDisposable. In most cases you won't need finalizer, most managed resources will be unavailable when finalizer is called, so there would be nothing to do there.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, my advice would be to pretend that there is no such thing as a finalizer, but make 100% certain that any IDisposable objects which are created get destroyed.  Even if finalizers are written 100% optimally, code which disposes of half its objects properly and lets finalizers handle the other half won't be as good as code which disposes of all its objects properly and doesn't use finalizers.  While it is true that the performance impact from finalizers which never run usually isn't too terrible, finalizers are difficult to write correctly, they can cause Heisenbugs if their code or the code that consumes them isn't written perfectly.  Further, successful implementation of finalizers will often require the creation of one or more WeakHandles whose only purpose is to support finalization.

Maybe the safety-net of finalization is worth the cost, but the cost can be considerable and the safety-net not as reliable as one might want.